# PHP preg_match_all and str_replace

Tags: php, str-replace

i have a little problem about preg_match_all and str_replace

```
<?
    $source = 'hello @user_name, hello @user_name2, hello @user_name3';
    preg_match_all("/@[\w\d_]*/s", $source, $search);
    foreach($search[0] as $result) {
        $source = str_replace($result, "<b>okay</b>", $source);
    }

    echo $source;
?>
```

the result is (wrong):

```
hello <b>okay</b>, hello <b>okay</b>2, hello <b>okay</b>3
```

the right result should be like this:

```
hello <b>okay</b>, hello <b>okay</b>, hello <b>okay</b>
```

anyone can help?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's happening because the first match, `@user_name`, will also match `@user_name2` and `@user_name3` (at least the `@user_name` part).  The way you've written it, it's working as it's supposed to.  You might want to look at [preg_replace()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php).  To test regex patterns, I always use [My Regex Tester](http://www.myregextester.com/) (which isn't actually mine, that's just the name of it).  Here's output from that site, complete with code generated:

```
Raw Match Pattern:
@[\w\d_]*

Raw Replace Pattern:
okay

PHP Code Example: 
<?php
$sourcestring="hello @user_name, hello @user_name2, hello @user_name3";
echo preg_replace('/@[\w\d_]*/s','<b>okay</b>',$sourcestring);
?>

$sourcestring after replacement:
hello <b>okay</b>, hello <b>okay</b>, hello <b>okay</b>
```

Comment: hi Crontab, thanks for your advice.. I try to use ` $source = preg_replace('/'.$result.'/', '<b>'.$result.'</b>', $source);` but result is same.. :(

Comment: I meant for you to use `preg_replace()` by itself instead of using `preg_match_all()` and `str_replace()` in tandem.

Comment: hmm, if I not using `preg_match_all`, i don't know what string followed by `@` that must be replaced to..? how is it?

Answer (score 0):

You problem is not with preg_match_all or preg_replace. The Problem is with str_replace.
After you created an search array, the first token contains value as "user_name", and **str_replace** function replace all three occurrences from the string. so 1 and 2 value remains as it is in string.

If you change your source as

```
$source = 'hello @user_name1, hello @user_name2, hello @user_name3';
```

it will work fine. otherwise you need to iterate array in reverse order